# Indeed Scraping Selenium/API CloudFlare

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cloudflare

My indeed scraping pipeline is broken. I think Indeed has updated their CloudFlare and i can't scrape job posting anymore. I tried to change selenium's header. I added a random wait time between each action. But CloudFlare is blocking me quickly.
I saw that their API is deprecated. How do you proceed to scrape job offers on your side ?

Best